# spring(integration) support for xml over http

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need to integrate our application with a legacy system which accepts xml requests(no contract) over http (POST) and sends another xml as response. Does spring or spring integration has any build in function to do so?

UPDATE: From Artem's suggestion I am using following code.

```
    <int:channel id="RequestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="ResponseChannel"/>
<int:gateway id="Gateway"
    service-interface="<package>.DataBuilder" default-request-channel="RequestHeaderEnricher"  default-reply-channel="ResponseChannel"/>

<int:channel id="RequestHeaderEnricher"/>
<int:header-enricher input-channel="RequestHeaderEnricher" output-channel="RequestChannel">
    <int:header name="Content-Type" value="text/xml" />
    <int:header name="Accept" value="text/xml" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="HttpGateway"
    request-channel="RequestChannel" url="http://<host>:<port>/XML_WS_A"
    http-method="POST"  charset="UTF-8" reply-timeout="6000" reply-channel="ResponseChannel"
    message-converters="messageConverters" request-factory="requestFactory">

</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<util:list id="messageConverters">
    <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"/>
</util:list>

<bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
  <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
  <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
</bean>

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="<package>.ExternalDataRequest"/>
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>

<bean id="requestFactory"
      class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <property name="connectTimeout" value="5000"/>
    <property name="readTimeout"    value="5000"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC provides for this case [`RestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#rest-client-access).

Spring integration provides more high abstraction over `RestTemplate` - [`<int-http:outbound-gateway>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/http.html#http-outbound)

For HTTP protocol it doesn't matter which type of data you send. So, you can simply send and receive an XML, e.g. as a String representation.

To get deal with some Object XML Mapping you should study: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#oxm and http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/xml.html.

I don't see yet other ways to help you, as your question is teorethical and abuts to the Docs.

Comment: Thanks Artem! From your suggestion, I implemented above code. However, I am seeing an exception............ `code` Throwable occurred: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [<package>.ExternalDataRequest] and content type [text/xml] `code` ................... What am I missing? (Yep, I know I am not binding the response, I will do that once the request is sent successfully..)

Comment: I am using 4.0.0.M2 version of spring integration and 4.0.0.RELEASE version of spring.

Comment: this line ` <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="<package>.ExternalDataRequest"/>` looks wrong. Or do you just hide your package?.. From other side do you have `XmlRootElement` on your `ExternalDataRequest` class? And I need to see more stack trace.